# How can I quickly grab items from a chest to my inventory?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play a lot of pvp games on Minecraft Bedrock. I play on a Mouse and Keyboard and I don't know what key to press to quickly grab and equip things from a chest.

Answer (score 13):

Not only can you shift+click one stack of items, but you can shift and double-click to obtain all the stacks of that same item.

Edit: I didn't realize you also asked to equip things. If you have any armor in your chest, you can shift+click to get it into your inventory, then right click (if it is in your hotbar) and you will equip the armor if you are currently not wearing any.

Comment: I guess that's a bedrock only feature, in java edition when I try to shift + double click, the stack moves on the first click and the second click doesn't do anything.

Comment: @KodosJohnson This should really be in the answer, but to move all items of the same type first click on one, then shift and double click on another one with the item still being dragged by your mouse

Comment: The part about right clicking the armor piece is correct but if you are wearing a piece of armor there already it will just swap them for you

Comment: This totally does not work in any way, shape, or form on the pocket edition of Minecraft (Android)...

Comment: Not working for me now on PC Bedrock.

Answer (score 1):

> Completely unrelated, but I'll answer anyway.

For these devices:

## PC (Window 10)

Just like Java Edition, you can <kbd>Shift</kbd> click on the hovered item to get the entire thing, or just like what [**@Norman Contreras**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/264288/norman-contreras) said, you can also double <kbd>Shift</kbd> click to get all of the same items in part of the hovered item.

## Mobile

In Mobile, there are 2 ways to accomplish this, depending on the UI Profile setting you are using:

#### Pocket

You can basically tap and hold the item to get the whole stack in the hovered area, but is not as quick, so it is better to use the one from Classic.

#### Classic

Very simple, tap on the item and it will select the entire stack in that hovered area, and tap anywhere in your inventory slot to put the whole thing in there. Faster to manage.

## Controller

> This bit is up to you, I don't know any controls on controllers.

Comment: It’s cool that you made this community wiki, but I noticed that you’re doing that with all your posts. I wouldn’t recommend doing this because you then get no reputation by doing it. Certain things can be community wiki, but I think you’re overusing it and it won’t work in your favor as you’ll have to wait longer to get [privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) than you should

Comment: @Penguin It's okay. With some helpful people to happily help make the answer better, it is okay making it community-wiki. I would rely on my question for the reputation, because it has a huge potential than my answers.

Comment: alright if you’re okay with that then that’s totally fine I would just make sure there’s nothing you want to get, you can eventually review stuff and decide what edits get approved and edit things instantly, so maybe something to think about. I bid you a good day fine sir !

Comment: I can't get this to work on mobile to transfer all stacks of a single item to my inventory.  How can I do that?